# Monads which preserve equalizers

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, monads

I'm looking for **examples of monads that preserve equalizers**, and an understanding of sufficient conditions that ensure this.

This is a situation where the advice given at the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/175105/354508) fails to be helpful, since of course any monad on a poset preserves equalizers. Considering the first part of that answer, a related question would be:

- What conditions on a theory $\mathbb{T}$ ensure that the corresponding monad on $\mathbf{Set}$ preserves equalizers?

This turns out to be quite subtle. For example, the free group and free abelian group monad don't preserve the equalizer diagram,
$$\emptyset \rightarrow \{0,1\}\rightrightarrows \{0,1\},$$
where the parallel morphisms are the two constant maps, since in the latter case the map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}^2$ sending $n$ to $(n,-n)$ equalizes the corresponding maps $\mathbb{Z}^2 \rightrightarrows \mathbb{Z}^2$ but doesn't factor through the trivial group.

As Max pointed out in the comments, the same is not applicable to monoids, since we have no inverses and so the comparable equalizer in the above is actually preserved. Indeed, for the free monoid monad we have that a word $w$ is in the equalizer of two parallel maps $F(f),F(g):F(X) \rightrightarrows F(Y)$ if and only if each of its constituent letters is (since there is a unique expression for any word), and hence if and only if the word is contained in the free monoid on the equalizer of $f$ and $g$. That is, this monad does preserve equalizers. For the free *commutative* monoid monad, on the other hand, the equalizer of the identity map and the map $\{0,1\}\to \{0,1\}$ which exchanges the elements is not preserved, since the map $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}^2$ sending $x$ to $(x,x)$ is the equalizer there!

The covariant powerset monad $P: \mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}$ doesn't preserve equalizers (as I'd initially thought, thanks Max) since considering the functions $\pi_1,(1-\pi_1):\{0,1\}^2 \rightrightarrows \{0,1\}$ we have $P\pi_1(\{(0,0),(1,1)\}) = \{0,1\} = P(1-\pi_1)(\{(0,0),(1,1)\})$, and similarly for three other possible choices, so the equalizer of these functions is not $P(\emptyset)$. A question which would require more work to check is:

- Does the double powerset functor (obtained by iterating the contravariant powerset functor) preserve equalizers?

---

*Background*: I've been studying the article "*Cartesian Monads on Toposes*" by Peter Johnstone where he studies monads on toposes preserving all finite limits, and finds that there really aren't very many (on $\mathbf{Set}$, they are in correspondence with strongly zero-dimensional locales, which is to say locales in which every open cover can be refined to a pairwise disjoint one, a very restrictive condition), so one motivation is to understand how much is gained by relaxing the conditions on the monad.

Comment: I don't understand your proof for the free group monad. Look at $f,g :\{a,b\}\to \{a,b\}$ with $f(a)=f(b) = a, g(a) = g(b)=b$; then $ab^{-1}$ is in the equalizer of $T(f), T(g)$, but not in $T(\mathrm{eq}(f,g))$. Am I missing something ? For monoids however this can't work, but it's related to some sort of positivity or non cancellativity of the monad - I don't know whether such a notion exists, but I raised a similar question here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3325594/does-a-free-algebra-over-a-nontrivial-monad-have-a-well-defined-dimension) (1/2)

Comment: Although my overall question was answered negatively, the question of whether one could make the idea of positivity or noncancellativity precise was not answered; and I think this to-define-notion is somehow related to your question as well (2/2)

Comment: You're right, it was a hasty calculation! I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Just read your edit, I hadn't considered commutative monoids indeed ! So you need your monad to be even more rigid than what I'd like to call positive. In fact the covariant power set monad is "commutative" as well, and so it doesn't preserve equalizers for the same reason: take $f,g: \{a,b,c,d\} \to \{a,b\}$ with $f(a) = f(b) = a, f(c)=f(d) = b$ and $g$ just swaps those, then $P(f)(\{a,c\} ) = P(g)(\{b,d\}) = \{a,b\}$ but of course $\mathrm{eq}(f,g)$ is empty. So monads that preserve equalizers are "positive" and "noncommutative" (I'd be super happy to figure what those words should mean)

Comment: Again, suitably edited. There really aren't as many examples of these as I would like!

Answer (score 1):

Turning my earlier comment into an answer, every [Cartesian monad](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cartesian+monad) preserves equalizers, in the sense of a monad on a Cartesian category whose functor part preserves pullbacks and whose naturality squares induced by the multiplication and unit are all pullbacks.

There are several examples of Cartesian monads on the nLab page, and there is a beautiful characterization due to Carboni and Johnstone of the Cartesian monads arising from algebraic theories: the appropriate theories are the *strongly regular* ones, those which can be axiomatized using equations in which the same variables appear in the same order on both sides. So associativity is OK, but commutativity and inverses are not, recovering precisely the examples discussed by you and Max.

The reason every Cartesian monad preserves equalizers is simply that any pullback-preserving functor $F:A\to B$ whose domain admits a terminal object preserves all finite connected limits, including equalizers. The argument is that the canonical lift of $F$ to a functor $\hat F:A\to B\downarrow F(1)$ preserves the terminal object (by construction) and pullbacks (because $F$ does), so preserves equalizers; but the forgetful functor $B\downarrow F(1)\to B$ preserves equalizers, so $F$ does as well.

Comment: Do you know if there is a converse to your first statement ?

Comment: Interestingly, the "Cartesian Monads" in the paper I mention in my question are monads whose functor part is cartesian in the sense that it preserves finite limits. I hadn't thought to check if the "locally cartesian" case. (cartesian is such a massively overused adjective...) The natural next question is whether the cartesian monads in Johnstone's paper, which arise from geometric morphisms, are cartesian in the sense you mention; I'll think about that. The examples on that nLab page distinguish the free (commutative) monoid monads though, which is nice.

Comment: @Max I certainly doubt the converse holds, as Cartesianness also requires conditions on $\mu$ and $\eta$, but I have no counterexample.

Comment: Indeed, by considering the naturality diagram for $\eta_X$ along itself at any object $X$ and noting that $\eta_{T(X)}$ and $T\eta_X$ are split monomorphisms, we see that any 'cartesian monad' must have a unit which is a monomorphism. Any geometric morphism which is not a surjection therefore induces a monad on its codomain which preserves equalizers (since it preserves all finite limits) but is not cartesian.

Comment: For future reference, the paper that Kevin mentioned is [this one](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-structures-in-computer-science/article/div-classtitleconnected-limits-familial-representability-and-artin-glueingdiv/54E93903F7D7321B98B64AE7CB3E7AE0).

Comment: Actually, my previous comment is almost vacuous when considering monads on $\mathbf{Set}$ (which people naturally like doing!) since by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1840142/354508) all but two monads on $\mathbf{Set}$ have units which are monic. Nonetheless, the terminal monad preserves all limits, so is a counterexample. (The other degenerate monad fails to preserve the equalizer of the two inclusions of a one element set into a two element set.)

Comment: I just realized there's a really easy example of a monad that is not cartesian but preserves equalizers : $M\times -$, for a monoid $M$